# show that:for every $x\in S$, there exsit $y,z,w\in S$, such $x=y^2+z^2+w^2$

Tags: number-theory

Define $S=\{a+b\cdot\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}|a,b\in Z\}$. Show that for every $x\in S$, there exit $y,z,w\in S$,such
$$x=y^2+z^2+w^2$$where $i$ such  $i^2=-1$

My attempt:

Since
$$\left(a+b\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^2=\left(a^2-ab-\dfrac{1}{2}b^2\right)+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}b(a-b)i$$

Comment: $S$ is the ring of integers for $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.  And you're asked to show that $n = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ always has a solution in the [Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer) $\mathcal{O}_K =  \mathbb{Z}[ \omega]$ with $ \omega = - \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \sqrt{-3} \right)   $.  If instead $K = \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}$ then $n = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ has a solution iff $n \neq 4^\ell(8k+7)$.

Comment: One precision is needed. For 0 in S, do you allow the obvious decomposition 0=0+0+0 ? If you don't, then the powerful theory of representations of elements of a field by a quadratic form applies and a necessary (and propobably sufficient) condition for an affirmative answer to your question would be that -1 is a sum of two squares in the quadratic field $Q(\sqrt {-3})$

Comment: @nguyenquangdo, no, no, and no.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14456/sum-of-squares-in-ring-of-integers for whom is interested in the problem on a general number field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}i} = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}i}{2}$ be the primitive cubic root of unity. It satisfies the identities
$$1 + \omega + \omega^2 = 0\quad\text{ and }\quad \omega^3 = 1$$
For any $x = a + b\omega \in S$, define $r$ according to following table.

$$\begin{array}{|cc:c:l|}
\hline
a & b & r & x + r^2\\
\hline
\text{even} & \text{ even } &  0 &  a + b\omega\\
\text{even} & \text{ odd }  & \omega^2 & a + (b+1)\omega\\
\text{odd} & \text{even} & 1 & (a+1) + b\omega\\
\text{odd} & \text{ odd} & \omega &(a-1) + (b-1)\omega\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

As one can see, independent of the parity of $a,b$, we have $x + r^2 = a' + b'\omega$ for some even $a'$ and $b'$. This means we can find a $\mu \in S$ such that $x + r^2 = 2\mu$.

Now for any $p, q \in S$, define $y, z, w$ by

$$
\begin{cases}
y &= p + q - r\\
z &= p\omega + q\omega^2\\
w &= p\omega^2 - q\omega
\end{cases}
$$
It is easy to see
$$\begin{align} y^2 + z^2 + w^2 
&= (p+q)^2 + (p\omega+q\omega^2)^2 + (p\omega^2 - q\omega)^2 - 2r(p+q) + r^2\\
&= (p^2 + 2pq + q^2) + (p^2\omega^2 + 2pq + q^2\omega) + (p^2\omega -2pq + q^2\omega^2) - 2r(p+q) + r^2\\
&= p^2(1+\omega^2+\omega) + 2pq(1+1-1) + q^2(1+\omega+\omega^2)-2r(p+q)+r^2\\
&= 2pq -2r(p+q)+r^2\\
&= 2(p-r)(q-r)-r^2
\end{align}
$$
If we choose $q = r+1$ and $p = r+\mu$, this becomes

$$y^2 + z^2+w^2 = 2\mu - r^2 = (x+r^2)-r^2 = x$$

This is precisely the decomposition we seek.

Comment: How to find this $y,z,w?$Thanks

Comment: @functionsug given $x = a + b\omega$, first figure out $r$ from parity of $a,b$ using given table. one then compute $\mu = \frac{x+r^2}{2}$, following by $p = r+1, q = r+\mu$ and substitute them into formula for $y,z,w$.